# Problem with inet_pton() call within Zend framework

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, youtube

I have a problem with using Zend framework (for YouTube data API). I created very simple PHP script for uploading YT videos using this API and it works almost everywhere - I tried it on 3 different machines (both Linux and WinXP). But after intalling it to 4th machine, I got this error:

```
Error:  inet_pton() [function.inet-pton]: Unrecognized address www.google.com    
Error type/ Nr.:    Warning - 2  
File:   /Zend/Validate/Ip.php    
Line:   62   
Line 62 source:  } else if ((@inet_pton($value) === false) ||(inet_ntop(@inet_pton($value)) !== $valueString)) {
```

I'm pretty sure it must be some configuration defect, but what's wrong? (PHP script is exactly similar on all instances)

Comment: This seems to point to a bug in `Zend_Validate_Ip`, try reading: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5186 And this google search: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=safari&rls=en-us&q=zend+framework+inet_pton%28%29+unrecognized+address&btnG=Search&aq=f&oq=&aqi=

Answer (score 1):

Modify /library/Zend/Validate/Ip.php between line 62 and 65 like :

```
} else if ((@inet_pton(gethostbyname($value)) === false) 
|| (inet_ntop(@inet_pton(gethostbyname($value))) !== $valueString)) {
        $this->_error();
        return false;
    }
```

$value must be an Ip Address and not a host name.